# Unable to make div cover the entire screen and entire content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a a div overlap all the other contents of the web page even the fixed navbar i.e. when i click a button then a div appears that covers the entire page and covers the entire content.But with the code i have written,it is unable to cover the navbar and also the other contents shift down

The image that appears in the background,i want it to cover the entire page even the fixed navbar.Here is my code:

```
  <body  style=" background-color: black"  onload="countview()" >
        <div class="main" style="height:100vh;display: none;text-align: center;background-image: url(hmk1.jpg);" id="main">
            <h1>Livie</h1>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">WHAT WE DO</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">SIGNUP FOR NEWSLETTER</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">FAQS</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag">CONTACT US</a>
            <a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="document.getElementById('main').style.display='none'"></a>
          </div>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="height:120px">
         <div style="clear: both;">
         <h1  style="cursor:pointer"><a href="#" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-link" onclick="v();"></a> Welcome to Livie</h1> 
   </nav>
```

In the third last line i have given the link which on click will display the background that covers entire screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want a div that will cover EVERYTHING...

```css
#COVER_EVERYTHING{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="COVER_EVERYTHING"></div>
<p>Some text</p>
<h1>Some more text</h1>
<span>LOL</span>
```

```css
#COVER_EVERYTHING{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!--<div id="COVER_EVERYTHING"></div>
and without....
-->
<p>Some text</p>
<h1>Some more text</h1>
<span>LOL</span>
```

Notice, it's easier to highlight without the DIV. The `z-index` on a position absolute property determines what it will be "higher" than if you will.